# Problems with layout using Floats, Clear, Display - Not Understanding when to use what - Improper coding

Tags: html, css

I am making a Image upload result box, somehow I managed to give it proper layout but elements of the result box doesn't seem right in 'Brackets View'

I struggle when it comes to use floats, clear and display. I get confused, I've tried to learn it 4-5 times till now but somewhere I fail to apply them properly.

Can someone guide me through this code while explaining when and where to use them..

Also, I use this technique to clear floats but sometimes it works and sometimes nothing happens:

```
.example
{
   content: ' ';
   display: block;
   clear: both;
}
```

My HTML & CSS:

```css
.files-bar {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 15px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
  box-shadow: 2px 3px 15px #E7E7E7;
}

.delete {
  float: right;
  background-color: #02BFC1;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: gothic;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 75px;
  border: 1px solid #02BFC1;
  font-size: 10pt;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.image-thumb {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  width: 160px;
  height: 120px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.img-thumb:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.image-name {
  font-size: 17pt;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.image-size {
  font-size: 13pt;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.file-status {
  display: block;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.progress-wrap {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
  color: #111;
  height: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.progress-meter {
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #02BFC1;
}

.up {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.cancel-upload {
  float: left;
  margin: -25px 0 0 -15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="files-bar">
  <button class="manage-btn delete">Delete</button>
  <img class="image-thumb" src="profile_image/2861e205148ccebc01cb9b1d8a4c6b0c.jpg">
  <p class="image-name">14217596f69f44507b.jpg</p>
  <p class="image-size">22 KB</p>
  <p class="file-status">File Uploaded Successfully!</p>
  <div class="progress-wrap">
    <!-- Progress bar -->
    <div class="progress-meter"></div>
  </div>
  <p class="cancel-upload">&#10006;</p>
</div>
```

Comment: CSS has developed a lot over the years, so the use for float (and clearfix) doesn't need to be used anymore. Use `display: flex` or `display: inline-block` instead.

A good flex introduction:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Sir I'm trying avoid 'Flex' due to its incompatibility with Internet Explorer of below version 10

Answer (score 0):

Float is not a good strategy for layout as it requires managing floats with `clear:both`. `clear` will clear any floats defined previously, in this case your delete button that is floated right.

Please see this quick reference on [float](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp) and [clear](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp) properties.

As mentioned in a comment above, using `display:flex` will give you greater control over layout. Here is a solution with minimal change to your original code. I set `display:flex` on the container defined by `div files-bar`, created a container for `progress` and one for the `delete` button. Together with the img, these sibling elements are flex items. Here is a good tutorial on using [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

And the complete code:

```css
.files-bar
{
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 700px;
   margin: 20px auto;
   padding: 15px;
   overflow: auto;
   border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
   box-shadow: 2px 3px 15px #E7E7E7;
   display:flex;
}

.delete
{
   background-color: #02BFC1;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   font-family: gothic;
   max-width: 75px;
   border: 1px solid #02BFC1;
   font-size: 10pt;
   padding: 10px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   cursor: pointer;
   display:inline-block;
}

.button-cell {
  text-align:right;
  flex-grow:1;
}

.image-thumb
{
   display: inline;
   width: 160px;
   height: 120px;
   margin-right: 20px;
}

.image-name
{
   font-size: 17pt;
   margin-top: 2px;
}

.image-size
{   
   font-size: 13pt;
   margin: 20px 0;
}

.file-status
{
   display: block;
   font-size: 12pt;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.progress-wrap
{
   float: left;
   width: 300px;
   height: 20px;
   color: #111;
   height: 5px;
   margin-top: 5px;
}

.progress-meter
{
   max-width: 300px;
   height: 5px;
   background: #02BFC1;
}

.up
{
   margin-left: 30px;
}

.progress {
  position:relative;
}

.cancel-upload
{
   position:absolute;
   right:4px;
   bottom:2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="files-bar">
    <img class="image-thumb flex-item" src="profile_image/2861e205148ccebc01cb9b1d8a4c6b0c.jpg">
    <div class="progress">
      <p class="image-name">14217596f69f44507b.jpg</p>
      <p class="image-size">22 KB</p>
      <p class="file-status">File Uploaded Successfully!</p>
      <div class="progress-wrap"> <!-- Progress bar -->
          <div class="progress-meter"></div>
      </div>
      <p class="cancel-upload">&#10006;</p>
    </div>
    <div class="button-cell">
      <button class="manage-btn delete flex-item">Delete</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE** – New snippet using absolute position within a relative positioned container.

Please review the following solution. Instead of using float, I positioned the elements absolute within the `files-bar` container. This will work in any browser.

```css
.files-bar
{
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 700px;
   margin: 20px auto;
   padding: 15px;
   overflow: auto;
   border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
   box-shadow: 2px 3px 15px #E7E7E7;
   position:relative;
}

.delete
{
   background-color: #02BFC1;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   font-family: gothic;
   max-width: 75px;
   border: 1px solid #02BFC1;
   font-size: 10pt;
   padding: 10px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   cursor: pointer;
   position:absolute;
   right:12px;
}

.image-thumb
{
   display: inline;
   width: 160px;
   height: 120px;
   margin-right: 20px;
   float:left;
}

.image-name
{
   font-size: 17pt;
   margin-top: 2px;
}

.image-size
{   
   font-size: 13pt;
   margin: 20px 0;
}

.file-status
{
   display: block;
   font-size: 12pt;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.progress {
  position:absolute;
  left:185px;
}

.progress-wrap
{
   width: 300px;
   height: 20px;
   color: #111;
   height: 5px;
   margin-top: 5px;
}

.progress-meter
{
   max-width: 300px;
   height: 5px;
   background: #02BFC1;
}

.up
{
   margin-left: 30px;
}

.cancel-upload
{
   position:absolute;
   right:4px;
   bottom:2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="files-bar">
    <img class="image-thumb" src="profile_image/2861e205148ccebc01cb9b1d8a4c6b0c.jpg">
    <div class="progress">
      <p class="image-name">14217596f69f44507b.jpg</p>
      <p class="image-size">22 KB</p>
      <p class="file-status">File Uploaded Successfully!</p>
      <div class="progress-wrap"> <!-- Progress bar -->
          <div class="progress-meter"></div>
      </div>
      <p class="cancel-upload">&#10006;</p>
    </div>
    <button class="manage-btn delete flex-item">Delete</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Sir I'm trying avoid 'Flex' due to its incompatibility with Internet Explorer of below version 10

Comment: Then you can float the image left and remaining containers will follow. The next element sibling to files-bar should use clear:both to reset clears. I'll update the answer with an example when possible. Alternatively use a simple table with one row and three columns. You can also use tableless with relative position files-bar and absolute position for each of the three elements.

Comment: I've published a new code snippet with a cross browser solution. Please review.

Comment: Sir, using absolute position I guess isn't good due to it's static behavior.. It's lengthy to make those responsive.. Sir can't it be done in a better way by just floating and clearing elements?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by static behavior. Absolute position is set in relation to the relative positioned container. Using floats here is likely the most complex path. I guess I don't understand what you mean by "brackets view." On a smaller viewport do you wish to render the layout differently or do you wish to keep the same layout, more compressed and without wrapping to a new line? Floats will make elements act as if inline and they will wrap if necessary. You can try setting `display:block` and `white-space:nowrap` to prevent this.

Comment: Sir first thanks for your support and answer!
And by the 'brackets view' I meant about "Brackets IDE" whose feature is Live View. I've posted an answer here with solution. You can check and let me know if you understood the same thing as I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Layout Problem Solved!**

The problem was that I wanted to put image on the left and other contents to the right of the image.

But there was too much use of floats, clear and display it was confusing also code was improper. And even though using them I was not getting the proper output. As the 'paragraph' element was also behind the image due to floats.

So, after some more trials I achieved that layout I wanted without using 'position' and too much of floats and clear.

**What I Applied:**

1. First, Floated the image to the left.
2. Put all of the other content below image inside a div class named 'rest'.
3. Floated 'rest div' to the left too.
4. Floated delete button to the right.
5. At last I've applied Clear Fix for "files-bar div."

It was simple that's it. All other elements adjusted itself. I just needed to put all other contents inside a div element and float it.

**Updated HTML:**

```
<div class="files-bar">
    <button class="delete">Delete</button>
    <img class="image-thumb" src="profile_image/1777859bb71d37aec3.jpg">
    <div class="rest">
        <p class="image-name">14217596f69f44507b.jpg</p>
        <p class="image-size">22 KB</p>
        <p class="file-status">File Uploaded Successfully!</p>
        <p class="cancel-upload">&#10006;</p>
        <div class="progress-wrap">          
            <div class="progress-meter"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*Default HTML's CSS has been removed which is also known as 'Doctor CSS'*

**Updated CSS:**

```
.files-bar
{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 600px;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
    box-shadow: 2px 3px 15px #E7E7E7;
}

.files-bar:after
{
    clear: both;
    content: '';
    display: block;
}

.image-thumb
{
    float: left;
    width: 160px;
    height: 120px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.rest {float: left;}

.delete
{
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #02BFC1;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: gothic;
    max-width: 75px;
    border: 1px solid #02BFC1;
    font-size: 10pt;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.image-name {font-size: 17pt;}

.image-size
{   
    font-size: 13pt;
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.file-status
{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12pt;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.progress-wrap
{
    width: 300px;
    height: 20px;
    color: #111;
    height: 5px;
}

.progress-meter
{
    max-width: 300px;
    height: 5px;
    background: #02BFC1;
}

.cancel-upload
{
    padding: 5px;
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```